# Angular Render html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this string which arrives from the server side.

```
  &lt;iframe scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowtransparency=&quot;true&quot; height=&quot;250&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; style=&quot;border:0;&quot; src=&quot;http://cdn.castplatform.com/scripts/au1324.html?subid=6e6c4c9092a4fd311393cd770c71ff05&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt
```

I want to present the html rendered.
When using $sce.trustAsHtml I get on the view:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" height="250" width="300" style="border:0;" src="http://cdn.castplatform.com/scripts/au1324.html?subid=6e6c4c9092a4fd311393cd770c71ff05"></iframe>
```

I would expect to get the html rendered (see picture) and not just the html stripped from the escape characters (as above):

[image: html rendered as I would expected]

What am I'm missing here?
Here is the js code:

```
$scope.field_value = $sce.trustAsHtml($sanitize(field_value));
```

and the view code:

```
<div ng-bind-html="field_value"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you send encoded value from server, then _trustAsHtml_ not helps, try send from server not encoded html

Comment: This is not encoded, If I populate field_value with the string without escape characters :

<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" height="250" width="300" style="border:0;" src="http://cdn.castplatform.com/scripts/au1324.html?subid=6e6c4c9092a4fd311393cd770c71ff05"></iframe>

then it is fine. Seems that I need to do another trustAsHtml as the first one only renders the escape chacters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another decoding step (copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290632/3563439):

```
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return function(text) {
        div.innerHTML = text;
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(div.textContent);
    };
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/8kphL7xe/