# HTML is not rendering single quotes it renders HTML Entities

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a DIV element where the Inner HTML is inserting

> &amp

into my Inner Text and it's getting rendered on the page.

**innerHTML** (And this exactly what gets rendered on the page:)

```
backbone that helps you collaborate in the &amp;lsquo;we&amp;rsquo; space through the same familiar Outlook environment that you use in the &amp;lsquo;me&amp;rsquo; space.
```

However the InnerText is correct.

**innerText** (this is the actual string stored in the database:)

```
backbone that helps you collaborate in the &lsquo;we&rsquo; space.
```

This happens in all browsers tested.

This is the actual div tag and it's also using angular:
[image]

Comment: Can you add your JS code here so we can have a look or even better yet add it to https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290396/angularjs-how-to-decode-html-entities-in-html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064309/decode-html-entity-in-angular-js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919533/using-html-entities-within-angular-strings